# How to make links one link per line, only in the footer via css?

Tags: css

I do not want these links display next to each other on the web page (only in the `<footer>` element, I want one link per line and I don't want to use `<br>`:

```
<footer>
    <p>Copyright © 2013 </p>
    <a href="http://www.link.com/">link.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.link.com/">link.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.link.com/">link.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.link.com/">link.com</a>
    <a href="http://www.link.com/">link.com</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `a` elements `display` property to `block`, which will cause each element to be displayed on their own line.

```
footer a{
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make them block elements:

```
footer > a { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

To match only specific links use for example `footer a { ... }` or add a class to the links.

Answer (score 2):

Set the style of your footer a tags to "block", this will cause them to take up the full line.

```
footer a{
   display: block
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
display:block; float:left; clear:left;
```

Comment: Some explanation as to what this is supposed to be would be helpful

Comment: +1 because it helped me. if you combine `float: left` and `display: block` the elements will be in the same line and you have to add `clear: left`

Comment: To venture a guess here, if you just do `display: block` that will likely cause the anchor so span the entire length of the parent element. Meaning that white space to the right of the text will still be clickable. This can feel odd to the user because it's not clear what they're clicking. Adding `float: left` will cause the length of the element to be based on the contents.